# PG::ConnectionBad (rails, solidus, ubuntu 15)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a strange issue with my psql, which was working just fine in my last session. Suddenly when I try to access my localhost server I get this issue

> PG::ConnectionBad 
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

- Money type has a fixed precision of 10 in `PostgreSQL 8.2` and below, and as of
- `PostgreSQL 8.3` it has a fixed precision of 19. PostgreSQLColumn.extract_precision*

I'm using Postgres 9.5 and Ubuntu 14.

When I type `"psql"` in terminal I get the message :

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?"
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to open a client / console connection to postgres before you've started the server. Here's information on starting the server:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html

*edit*
As you're on Ubuntu try:

`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out, how come the database server is suddenly off though? its been working just fine for a week :S

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working, still getting the same error although maybe im doing it wrong. I tried typing
 "$ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &" and I get this output : [1] 4470. But not sure to make of it. :/

Comment: You didn't type the "$" did you?!

Comment: More info then please. What's your OS and how did you install it? (Package manager etc?)

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 15.10, I installed it trough usb, not sure what you mean there. :P 
I've developed the project for two weeks without touching the postgres stuff and its been working excellent till this sudden error. :/

Comment: Ok, so you're using Ubuntu but you didn't use 'apt-get install postgres' ? Have you tried 'service postgres start' ?

Comment: oh sorry, yea i did use apt-get install. was a bit confused as to what you meant. :P  When I try that I get : "Failed to start postgres.service: Unit postgres.service failed to load: No such file or directory."

Comment: Sorry, if this guide doesn't help you someone else will need to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL think I've offered all I can on this one

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort Tom! I'll keep searching, hopefully Ill find a solution soon! :)

Comment: Ah I fixed it with a simple "sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart" (was the only restart/stop&start command that would work for some reason it seems.

Comment: Mind if I make it my answer so I can get an accept? 

Comment: @Makkafon you need to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the up arrow to the left of my answer

Comment: ahh seems i dont have enough rep. :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you already logged in to postgres? (sudo -i -u user) user being the name of your postgres account.

PostgreSQL server should be running all the time.

Comment: I type it directly into the terminal right? In that case, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Since I've used Brew to install PG, the fix that worked for me is in the steps below:

```sh
$ brew uninstall postgresql

$ exec $SHELL

$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database

$ brew services start postgresql
```